# Laravel5.6 & AJAX: it is possible to use {{ }} expression as jQuery.load() parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

When I saw below example I conclude that it's possible to use `{{ }}` expressions as in blade template.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url : "{{ url('/api/login') }}",
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    user   : user,
    passwd : passwd
  })
  :
});
```

I thought what if laravel understand `{{ url('') }}`, it will understand `{{route()}}` and created below request:

```
changeFragment(newFragment){

    let fragmentUrn = '{{ route( "admin.GetFragmentViaAjax", ["fragment" => "requests_all"]) }}';

    this.$MainContent.load(fragmentUrn, (response, status, xhr) => {
        status === 'success' ?  resolve() : reject(xhr);
    });
}
```

I got following error in console:

[image]

It's really possible to use `{{}}` in AJAX requests?

Comment: Is your JS written in a `.blade` file?

Comment: @linktoahref, No, my js written in `.js` file. Understood. Because I do not add scripts in markup, I can not use `{{ }}` in my js. Everything is correct?

Comment: You cannot use `{{ }}` unless it is a `.blade` file as it is a blade directive

Comment: @linktoahref, O'K, got it. Thank you for the answer and sorry for previous inaccurate question. It was take some time to concertize the error.

Comment: Personally I would put this variable somewhere in the dom using blade and retrieve it with a jquery selector.

Comment: @Thomas Moors, Good idea!

Answer (score 0):

**Just try:**

JavaScript:

```
function changeFragment(newFragment){
    let fragmentUrn = "{{ route('GetFragmentViaAjax', ['fragment' => 'statistic_top'])}}"
$(".MainContent").load(fragmentUrn);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[linktoahref](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5808894/linktoahref) understood that my first example was a part of the js-code written directly in blade view. Commonly, it is no good practice, so generally it's impossible to use `{{ }}` and other laravel tool inside JavaScript.